# Entering data in a table using a text box in a form

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a form which enables a user to change the data within a table using a text box. I have limited knowledge of VBA and SQL but I tried to have a go using SQL.

```
UPDATE WIP SET WIP.[Current Stock] = [WIP]![Current Stock]
WHERE (((WIP.[Part Code])=[Forms]![Stock In]!Text27));
```

This is what I came up with but it doesnt seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you put the sql in a query and provided a button or such like for the user? (There is a wizard for a button.) If so, what do you mean by "does not work"? Any error messages? Did you test with the query design window?

Comment: Yes im using the query at the minute. When the data is entered and the user presses enter a warning box appears, telling the user that the data entered will change the table. But another warning box appears telling the user how many rows will be changed, everytime it says "0" rows will be changed

Comment: Are you sure that whatever you put in text27 is a Part Code?

Comment: In the form I have a combo box, allowing the user to select the part which they want to update/add to. Once they have selected the part they enter the amount they wish to update. This is "Text27"

Comment: UPDATE [Manager Table] 
INNER JOIN [Team Table] ON [Manager Table].[Manager ID] = [Team Table].[Manager ID] 
SET [Team Table].Points = Forms![Manager Table]![Players Subform]!txtteamtotal
WHERE ((([Team Table].[Team ID])=[Forms]![Manager Table]![Team Table Subform]![Team ID]));
I used this piece of SQL a few years ago for a project for school. It works but when I try and copy it into my new database it doesnt

Comment: It dies work. The query runs according to your previous comment `"0" rows will be changed` means that all the names are found. What is not found is Team ID. Change this `[Forms]![Manager Table]![Team Table Subform]![Team ID])` in your query to an actual team ID and see where you get. Your INNER JOIN may have got rid of teams you thought were there.

Comment: Also try `SELECT [Manager Table].*,[Team Table].* FROM [Manger Table] INNER JOIN [Team Table] ON [Manager Table].[Manager ID] = [Team Table].[Manager ID]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its the first SQL code im trying to fix. The 'manager table' one is an old one. I need to change the 'current stock' one somehow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried google? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

The logic of your SQL update statement may be incorrect. You are trying to set `Current Stock` to `Current Stock` for any rows where `Part Code` is equal to what you type in the textbox...
If you don't type in something that exists in `Part Code`, you get "0 rows will be changed".

Try changing your code to match the following (like from the link above):

```
UPDATE table_to_update
SET column_to_update=value_to_enter
WHERE criteria_column=criteria_value
```

Comment: The sql code given seems to update all records, i only want to update one at a time as their are different amounts of each part in the table. How can this be achieved?

Comment: That is what my example above does: *update field `column_to_update` in table `table_to_update` with the value `value_to_enter`, but only for the row(s) where field `criteria_column` is `criteria_value`*. In order to update only one row, `criteria_column` could be the ID column and `criteria_value` could be a unique ID for the row.

Comment: I unable to try the SQL at this time but in theory this should allow the user to select the part, type in the amount into the text box (Value_to_enter) and update the WIP table with the ID Column being (Current Stock) and the Unique ID being (Part Code)?

Comment: Did any answers help you? Or did you solve it in another way? Mark the question as answered by clicking the checkmark beside an answer or submit your own answer if you solved it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE WIP SET WIP.[Current Stock] = [Forms]![Stock In]![Current Stock] 
WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=[Forms]![Stock In]![Text27]
```

Or

```
UPDATE WIP SET WIP.[Current Stock] =  
       WIP.[Current Stock]+[Forms]![Stock In]![Current Stock] 
WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=[Forms]![Stock In]![Text27]
```

---

Re comments

Guessing, I would imagine:

```
UPDATE WIP SET WIP.[Current Stock] 
       = [WIP]![Current Stock] + [Forms]![Stock In]![Text27]
WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=[Forms]![Stock In]![Combo19]
```

Or

```
UPDATE WIP SET WIP.[Current Stock] = [Forms]![Stock In]![Text27]
WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=[Forms]![Stock In]![Combo19]
```

Comment: In the question you have just deleted, you say it does not update any records, in the comments above I suggested ways to track down the problem. What was the result of your tests using the methods I suggested?

Comment: The same warning message appeared when i tried your methods. Im going to try the other answer to see if i get different results

Comment: Michael, did you try `Also try SELECT [Manager Table].*,[Team Table].* FROM [Manger Table] INNER JOIN [Team Table] ON [Manager Table].[Manager ID] = [Team Table].[Manager ID]` as I suggest sometime ago? What was the result?

Comment: Did you try  Change this [Forms]![Manager Table]![Team Table Subform]![Team ID]) in your query to an actual team ID and see where you get? These are suggestions from over three hours ago. You have posted a new question since, and deleted it yet you have not yet replied to my suggestions.

Comment: Im not trying to change the one you are quoting. it works fine in another database.

Comment: 'UPDATE WIP 
SET WIP.[Current Stock] = [WIP]![Current Stock]
WHERE (((WIP.[Current Stock])=[Forms]![Stock In]![Text27]));'

Comment: Michael, I need to know if the query returns any records, do you know how to do that? I can only quote what you give me, if it is not relevant, please do not include it.

Comment: Michael, please try a straight select query. Does it return any records?

Comment: Yes it does. Returns everything I need.

Comment: Great! Now if you add a where statement : `WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=` Does it return anything? And please tell me the partcode you use.

Comment: So with the Stock In form open, does `WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=[Forms]![Stock In]![Text27]` return anything? When text27=ASM-00065

Comment: Text27 is the box where the user enters the amount of that specific part to put into the table. In the Stock In form I have a combo box which allows the user to view all the parts. Once a part is selected another box shows the current amount that is in stock. then i have one more text box, we know this one as 'text27'

Comment: There is your problem. Where does the user put the part to be updated? What is the name of the control? As an aside, please do yourself a favour and give the controls descriptive names.

Comment: It should be linked in the sql (not sure how to do that) They select the part from the combo box.

Comment: Please answer my questions. What is the name of the combo?

Comment: The combobox is called "combo19"

Comment: Okay. Using the SELECT query with the In Stock form open, add `WHERE WIP.[Part Code]=[Forms]![Stock In]![Combo19]` to the query and see if it returns anything. Make sure to select ASM-00065 in the combo before running the query.

Comment: Now how can I edit the SQL to change it to a Update query. Updating the records in the WIP table?

Comment: With any luck. Post the sql here if you have any problems.

Comment: I havent got the SQL thats why I was asking "how can I edit the SQL to change it to an update query?"

Comment: Ah! I just saw the Now. I do not know for sure, because you have not supplied information for this database, just for some other database. I will add some guess work to my answer.

Comment: I'll give you some quick info. Its a stock control Database. Several tables and forms. The main table Im focusing on is (WIP) and the fields im focusing on are (Part Code) and (Current Stock). There is a form called (Stock In/Out) This is the one I want to use for updating the table (WIP)

Comment: You have already accepted an answer, what do you want from me?

Comment: Didnt mean to do that. Ive yet to try the SQL you have given above. I'll give it a go now

Comment: It doesnt seem to recognise (Text27)

Comment: It asks me to enter parameter value

Comment: This is the information you supplied. Is the Stock In form open? What is the name of the control that you put quantities into? Do you add the quantities to the existing stock field for, say, ASM-00065?

Comment: Yes its open. (Text27) yes 
and opening another question on how to do something different causes less confusion

Comment: "haha i think i was the whole time anyway" Are you serious? Is that what you got from the above?

Comment: I got it sorted for putting stock in now I just need to sort one out for taking stock out! Calm down