# Updating tables pt2

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entering data in a table using a text box in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364967/entering-data-in-a-table-using-a-text-box-in-a-form)

This question is similar to my last but in this case I want to be able to remove certain amounts from a table using a text box in a form.

Same scenario, the user inputs the data they want to remove from the table.

For example;
The user has taken out 15 MEC-0004 from stock and wants to update the table. They open the (Stock In/Out) form, select the part (using a combo box) and then alter the amount in the table by typing in 15 into the text box and pressing save or enter.

The SQL code for the last question is something like this:

```
UPDATE table_to_update
SET column_to_update=value_to_enter
WHERE criteria_column=criteria_value
```

I could also try `VBA` if someone pointed me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question - can you elaborate?

Comment: How do I remove certain amounts from a table using a text box in a form?

Comment: What goes? I am just wasting my time in this long conversation on this very topic while you post new questions and delete them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364967/entering-data-in-a-table-using-a-text-box-in-a-form/12370807#comment16638694_12370807

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the value itself in the `set` clause.  So a query to change the amount of stock by a relative value would look like:

```
UPDATE  stock_table
SET     amount = amount - @Amount
WHERE   stock_id = @StockId
```

Comment: (@Amount) would have to be (Text27) as this is where the user types in the amount they wish to remove from the table. Is this possible?

Comment: SQL doesn't know about text boxes.  It's up to you to put the text from the text box in a parameter to send to SQL Server.  There should be plenty of tutorials for that!

Comment: You have just told me that your form does not have a text27.

Comment: @Andromar SQL is a generic term, the OP, in this duplicate question, is using MS Access.

Comment: @Remou: I had no idea you could use `[Forms]![Stock In]![Combo19]` in Access SQL, interesting.

Comment: Oddly enough, you can even refer to it as a parameter with DAO and VBA.  `qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![Stock In]![Combo19]") = [Forms]![Stock In]![Combo19]`

Comment: 'UPDATE WIP SET WIP.[Current Stock] = [Current Stock]-Forms![Stock In]!Txtinput
WHERE (((WIP.[Part Code])=[Forms]![Stock In]![Combo0]));'
This is the SQL I have come up with. It runs with no error messages but doesnt update the table. It doesnt even return any records when the Stock out form is open